# Hacker rank List Prepare

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, nested

**Sample Input:**

```
12
insert 0 5
insert 1 10
insert 0 6
print
remove 6
append 9
append 1
sort
print
pop
reverse
print
```

**Output :**

```
[6, 5, 10]
[1, 5, 9, 10]
[9, 5, 1]
```

This is my Code and it gives me this error message. Why?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    l=[]
    N = int(input())
    for z in range(N):
        x=input().split()
        if (x[0]=="insert"):
            l.insert(int(x[1]),int(x[2]))
        elif(x[0]=="print"):
            print(l)
        elif(x[0]=="remove"):
            l.remove(int(x[1]))
        elif (x[0]=="append"):
            l.append(x[1])
        elif(x[0]=="sort"):
            l.sort()
        elif(x[0])=="pop":
            l.pop()
        elif(x[0]=="reverse"):
            l.reverse()
```

Error Message - Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/submission/20220617/03/45/hackerrank-3495035b4042c8bc0c55e799a2d2e687/code/Solution.py", line 15, in 
l.sort()
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appended string value at `x[0] == "append"`.

It should work when you change to `l.append(int(x[1])`

Answer (score 1):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = int(input())
    myList = []
    
    for i in range(N):
        command = input().split()
        if command[0] == 'insert':
            myList.insert(int(command[1]), int(command[2]))
        elif command[0] == 'print':
            print(myList)
        elif command[0] == 'remove':
            myList.remove(int(command[1]))
        elif command[0] == 'append':
            myList.append(int(command[1]))
        elif command[0] == 'sort':
            myList.sort()
        elif command[0] == 'pop':
            myList.pop()
        elif command[0] == 'reverse':
            myList.reverse()
```